# Wrap C++ Expression Templates for Python Bindings

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++17, pybind11

Lets assume we have a very simple `Expression Template` implementation in `C++`.

```cpp
/* MyHeader.hpp */

#pragma once

#include <array>

template<class VT>
struct Vector
{
    const VT& operator~() const { return static_cast<const VT&>(*this); }
};

template<class T>
struct MyVector : public Vector<MyVector<T>>
{
    MyVector(T a, T b, T c) { data = { a, b, c }; }

    const T& operator[](size_t i) const { return data[i]; }

    std::array<T, 3> data;
};

template<class LHS, class RHS, class OP>
struct BinaryExpression : public Vector<BinaryExpression<LHS, RHS, OP>>
{
    BinaryExpression(const LHS& lhs, const RHS& rhs, OP op)
        : lhs(lhs), rhs(rhs), op(op) { }

    auto operator[](size_t i) const { return op(lhs[i], rhs[i]); }

    const LHS& lhs; const RHS& rhs; const OP op;
};

template<class LHS, class RHS>
decltype(auto) operator+(const Vector<LHS>& lhs, const Vector<RHS>& rhs)
{
    return BinaryExpression(~lhs, ~rhs, [](auto x, auto y) { return x + y; });
}

template<class LHS, class RHS>
decltype(auto) operator*(const Vector<LHS>& lhs, const Vector<RHS>& rhs)
{
    return BinaryExpression(~lhs, ~rhs, [](auto x, auto y) { return x * y; });
}
```

Alongside some `Python` bindings, using `pybind11`.

```cpp
/* PyBindings.cpp */

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/operators.h>

#include "MyHeader.hpp"

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(ExprTemplTest, m) {
    using VecType = MyVector<int>;

    py::class_<VecType>(m, "MyVector")
        .def(py::init<int, int, int>())
        .def("__getitem__", [](VecType& vec, const size_t& idx) { return vec[idx]; })
        .def(py::self + py::self)
        .def(py::self * py::self);
}
```

Now the issue is that (by design) all expressions need to be known at compile time. So this Python script fails.

```py
      1 import ExprTemplTest as ett
      2 v1 = ett.MyVector(14,2,9)
      3 v2 = ett.MyVector(14,2,9)
----> 4 v1 + v2

# TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
#   (self: ExprTemplTest.MyVector, arg0: ExprTemplTest.MyVector) 
#   -> BinaryExpression<MyVector<int>,MyVector<int>,<lambda_38af1187403d07160e9ae446e682a6fb> >
```

That is, we'd have to define `py::class_<BinaryExpression<MyVector<int>,MyVector<int>,<lambda_38af1187403d07160e9ae446e682a6fb>>>` in `PyBindings.cpp` (which is a bit tricky since there is a lambda in it). And furthermore, for any other expression (like `v1 + v2 * v2`) we'd have to define another class, and so on.

Is it possible to somehow wrap the `BinaryExpression` types into a generic class which Python can handle?

Comment: If you have a generic version of BinaryExpression to call from Python, or could construct a generic one in Python using generic accessors to the data, then you can add an `__add__` function to the base class in Python and have that called. I just don't see how to do that without duplicating the BinaryExpression code in Python. And completely aside, I normally would recommend cppyy (http://cppyy.org) for cases like this, but your code actually uncovered a bug (thanks for that), so I'm fixing that first. :)

Comment: pybind binds *one* C++ class to *one* python class. This implies that you need to instantiate all template classes before binding it to pybind. Therefore the problem (of many template classes) needs to be managed on C++ side. Moving `OP` from template parameters to a member (`std::function`) might be acceptable but (probably) inefficient solution. Take a look at eigen library and it's bindings in pybind, you might find it helpful.